# button onclick: "not a function" when part of form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run some javascript when a button is clicked, which I will have in a `uploadfile()` function, eg:

`<input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info" button id="uploadfile" onclick="uploadfile()">`

This works fine (calls the `uploadfile()` function). However, if this button is part of a form as follows:

```
<form action = "http://localhost/uploaded" method = "POST" 
            enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <input type = "file" name = "file" class="form-control-file">
            <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload Image" button id="uploadfile" onclick="uploadfile()">
            </form>
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: uploadfile is not a function

Comment: send us the html an js please

Comment: It isn't possible for it to have worked on the original button outside of a form and not on the one inside the form. More than likely it DID work, but something else occurred thus preventing it's outcome from occurring (such as the form submitting... it is a submit button after all) but the error you are getting makes no sense if that's the only change you made.

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` won't work inside a form, see [onClick event doesn't work inside form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770523/onclick-event-doesnt-work-inside-form-tag). The solution is to use `onsubmit`, eg:

```
<form action = "http://localhost/uploaded" method = "POST" onsubmit="uploadfile()"
            enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <input type = "file" name = "file" class="form-control-file">
            <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload Image">
            </form>
```